How to load raylib font in assembly?
Problem:
I have computer science classes, we learn assembly using fasm, classes rely on win api, but i use linux so i've got approval to use external libraries.
I've chose Raylib.
Problem is that I can't call LoadFont(Ex) without program segfaulting.
I tried to store structure in font by reserving 64 bytes, and tried to store pointer to the data before that, but no luck.
Progress:
format ELF64

section ".data" writeable
    screenWidth:    dd 800
    screenHeight:   dd 600
    windowTitle:    db "raylib [text] example - font loading", 0
    codepoints:     times 512 dd 0
    fontFile:       db "km.ttf", 0
    text1:          db "Окей, Okay!", 0
    text2:          db "С Новым Годом!", 0

section ".bss"
    font: rb 64

section '.text' executable
    public _start
    extrn printf
    extrn _exit
    extrn InitWindow
    extrn WindowShouldClose
    extrn CloseWindow
    extrn BeginDrawing
    extrn EndDrawing
    extrn ClearBackground
    extrn DrawText
    extrn DrawTextEx
    extrn LoadFontEx
    extrn UnloadFont

_start:
    mov rdi, 400
    mov rsi, 300
    mov rdx, windowTitle
    call InitWindow

init_ascii:
    mov rcx, 0x20 ; rcx is codepoints count
init_ascii_loop:
    mov [codepoints + rcx - 0x20], rcx


    inc rcx
    cmp rcx, 127
    jne init_ascii_loop

init_cyrillic:
    mov rcx, 0x400 ; rcx is codepoints count
init_cyrillic_loop:
    mov [codepoints + rcx - 0x400], rcx

    inc rcx
    cmp rcx, 0x6c1
    jne init_cyrillic_loop

    ; Load the font
    mov rdi, fontFile           ; font file
    mov rsi, 32                 ; font size
    mov rdx, codepoints         ; codepoints
    mov rcx, 211                ; codepoints count
    call LoadFontEx
    mov [font], rax

.again:
    call WindowShouldClose
    test rax, rax
    jnz .over
    call BeginDrawing

    mov rdi, 0xFF181818
    call ClearBackground

    mov rdi, text1
    mov rsi, 100
    mov rdx, 100
    mov rcx, 20
    mov r8, 0xFFFFFFFF
    call DrawText

    ; mov rdi, text1
    ; mov rsi, 100
    ; mov rdx, 100
    ; mov rcx, 20
    ; mov r8, 0xFFFFFFFF
    ; call DrawTextEx

    call EndDrawing
    jmp .again

.over:
    call CloseWindow
    mov rdi, 0
    call _exit


Why mov r10, 211 ? Shouldn't that be ecx?

changed, no result (still segfaults)

i use linux, so my calling convention is System V AMD64 ABI
And that's not windows, functions ending in Ex is raylib functions

Oh, so functions like DrawText are from raylib, not the WinAPI functions of the same name?  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext).  In that case yes, RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9 in that order.

i have problem with not supplying arguments, but with storing the results.
I need that to supply it to DrawTextEx as a first argument, and then to pass to UnloadFont

LoadFontEx seems to return a Font which is a struct so you will probably need to use the hidden argument method. Load the address of the result (font) into rdi move all other arguments to make room for it.

Have you checked memory with a debugger, or tried strace to see what open system call it's attempting to find your .ttf?  I don't think you're writing past the end of your 512 x 4 = 2K buffer, even though you are doing 8-byte stores that overlap by 7 for no apparent reason.  (And codepoints should be in .bss instead of .data if you're going to zero-init it and fill it with a loop.)

i don't know how to use debugger yet, nor do I know of strace, i'll try now

I tried debugging, it errored with: ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.

nvm thats a libbacktrace issue somehow

@Jester I've tried to look at assembly generated by compiler explorer, but can't make sense of it, what is going on? Can you please explain it?

You disabled optimization and compiled a big function so the asm is a mess.  https://godbolt.org/z/P1Gfbo75h shows a function that just calls another which returns a Font and accesses one of the members of the struct.  Note how it passes a pointer to space for the return-value object, as documented by the calling convention for types larger than 16 bytes.  (I used volatile so I could enable optimization and have only those variables not optimized away.)

The Problem is likely on storing structure in the font variable reserved with 64 bytes in .bss.  It may not be sufficient or correctly aligned for a complex structure like a Font.

I've figured it using this
Basically, function LoadFont stores new font on the stack instead of returning it as a value, that's why we pass rsp (register (for) stack pointer) into rdi
Later to call DrawTextEx we should have font structure loaded into rsp as the last data on stack, so that function can safely reference it (i think thats what happens on lines 68-73, if im wrong correct me please)
format ELF64

section ".data" writeable
    screenWidth:    dd 850
    screenHeight:   dd 300
    windowTitle:    db "Моя программа.", 0
    fontFile:       db '../assets/km.ttf', 0
    text:          
        .message:   db "Программировать наАссемблер на FASM — это классно!", 0
        .xy:        dd 100.0, 100.0
        .fontSize:  dd 30.0
        .spacing:   dd 0.0
                        ; unicode    
    codepoints:     dd  32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 0, \
                    \   ; cyrillic
                    1024, 1025, 1026, 1027, 1028, 1029, 1030, 1031, 1032, 1033, 1034, 1035, 1036, 1037, 1038, 1039, 1040, 1041, 1042, 1043, 1044, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1048, 1049, 1050, 1051, 1052, 1053, 1054, 1055, 1056, 1057, 1058, 1059, 1060, 1061, 1062, 1063, 1064, 1065, 1066, 1067, 1068, 1069, 1070, 1071, 1072, 1073, 1074, 1075, 1076, 1077, 1078, 1079, 1080, 1081, 1082, 1083, 1084, 1085, 1086, 1087, 1088, 1089, 1090, 1091, 1092, 1093, 1094, 1095, 1096, 1097, 1098, 1099, 1100, 1101, 1102, 1103, 1104, 1105, 1106, 1107, 1108, 1109, 1110, 1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118, 1119, 1120, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1124, 1125, 1126, 1127, 1128, 1129, 1130, 1131, 1132, 1133, 1134, 1135, 1136, 1137, 1138

section ".bss" writeable
    font:           rb 48

section '.text' executable
    public _start
    extrn printf
    extrn _exit
    extrn InitWindow
    extrn WindowShouldClose
    extrn CloseWindow
    extrn BeginDrawing
    extrn EndDrawing
    extrn ClearBackground
    extrn DrawTextEx
    extrn LoadFontEx
    extrn UnloadFont

_start:
    mov rdi, [screenWidth]
    mov rsi, [screenHeight]
    mov rdx, windowTitle
    call InitWindow

; load font
    mov rdi, font
    mov esi, fontFile ; move offset of "km.ttf" into esi
    mov edx, 32 ; move 32 into edx
    mov rcx, codepoints ; move address of codepoints into rcx
    mov r8d, 211 ; move 211 into r8d
    call LoadFontEx

.again:
    call WindowShouldClose
    test rax, rax
    jnz .over
    call BeginDrawing

    mov rdi, 0xfffafafa ; a g b r
    call ClearBackground

    sub rsp, 48
    movdqa  xmm3, [font]  ; tmp136, f
    movups  [rsp], xmm3     ; tmp136
    movdqa  xmm4, [font+16]  ; tmp137, f
    movups  [rsp+16], xmm4  ; tmp137
    movdqa  xmm5, [font+32]  ; tmp138, f
    movups  [rsp+32], xmm5  ; tmp138
    mov edi, text.message
    movq xmm0, [text.xy]
    movss xmm1, [text.fontSize]
    movss xmm2, [text.spacing]
    mov esi, 0xff181818
    call DrawTextEx
    add rsp, 48

    call EndDrawing
    jmp .again

.over:
    ; unload font
    sub rsp, 48
    movdqa  xmm3, [font]
    movups  [rsp], xmm3
    movdqa  xmm4, [font+16]
    movups  [rsp+16], xmm4
    movdqa  xmm5, [font+32]
    movups  [rsp+32], xmm5
    call    UnloadFont      
    add     rsp, 48   

    ; close window
    call CloseWindow
    mov rdi, 0
    call _exit


It stores to the return-value object, which RDI points to.  That is how a function returns a large object by value in the AMD64 System V calling convention.  It doesn't have to be on the stack, although that's where compilers will normally put it so they can be sure it's not the same object as something this opaque function might read or write.  An asm caller might know that won't be the case so you can point RDI at some static storage if you want, instead of copying from stack space.

so, I can move address of font reserved in .bss section into RDI, and it will store the font in font? What about supplying arguments to UnloadFont?

Yes, think of it like a hidden arg where you can pass a pointer to memory where it will store the return value.  Re: second question: UnloadFont takes a Font object by value; that's why you have to copy it to stack memory, not just pass a pointer. Because that's how the x86-64 SysV calling convention passes objects larger than 16 bytes.
